# Django Rest Framework model object returns stored value of a field with choices

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a project with Django Rest Framework and I have a complex `ViewSet` that uses several models and serializers to compound a large and complex json. Everything works fine, but I notice that `HotelSerializer`, that is a `ModelSerializer`, is returning the stored value of field `category`, instead of the human readable value of its model `choices`.

This is the model:

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    ONE_STAR = '*'
    TWO_STARS = '**'
    THREE_STARS = '***'
    FOUR_STARS = '****'
    FIVE_STARS = '*****'
    GRAND_TOURISM = 'GRAND_TOURISM'
    NA = 'NA'
    SPECIAL = 'SPECIAL'
    ECO = 'ECO'
    BOUTIQUE = 'BOUTIQUE'

    HOTEL_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (ONE_STAR, _('*')),
        (TWO_STARS, _('**')),
        (THREE_STARS, _('***')),
        (FOUR_STARS, _('****')),
        (FIVE_STARS, _('*****')),
        (GRAND_TOURISM, _('Grand Tourism')),
        (NA, _('NA')),
        (SPECIAL, _('Special')),
        (ECO, _('Eco-Hotel')),
        (BOUTIQUE, _('Boutique-Hotel'))
    )

    company = models.OneToOneField(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, verbose_name=_('Company'))
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=_('Code'))
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='hotels', verbose_name=_('Zone'))
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=HOTEL_CATEGORY_CHOICES, verbose_name=_('Category'))
    capacity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Capacity'))
    position = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, verbose_name=_('Position'))
    in_pickup = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('In pickup?'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Is active?'))
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Latitude'))
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Longitude'))
```

This is the serializer:

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=models.Hotel.HOTEL_CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Hotel
        fields = ('company', 'code', 'zone', 'category', 'capacity', 'position', 'in_pickup', 'is_active', 'latitude', 'longitude')
        depth = 4

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclude = kwargs.pop('exclude', None)

        super(HotelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if exclude is not None:
            for field_name in exclude:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

This is the ViewSet function where I get the `Hotel` model information:

```
def get_hotel(self, company_id):
    hotel = Hotel.objects.get(company=company_id)

    import ReservationsManagerApp.serializers
    return ReservationsManagerApp.serializers.HotelSerializer(hotel, exclude=('company',)).data
```

And this is the result I get:

```
"hotel": {
        "code": "xxxx...",
        "zone": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Zona hotelera",
            "city": {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Cancun",
                "code": "998",
                "state": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Quintana Roo",
                    "code": "98",
                    "country": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Mexico",
                        "code": "MX",
                        "calling_code": "52"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "category": "GRAND_TOURISM",
        "capacity": 300,
        "position": "1.00",
        "in_pickup": true,
        "is_active": true,
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null
    },
```

You can see that the `Category` field returns the value `'GRAND_TOURISM'`, instead of  its human readable version of its `choices`: `'Grand Tourism'`. It even misses the translation, so it must return `'Gran Turismo'`.

I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior AFAIK, but it is easy to fix.

One solution is to just do

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  category = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=Hotel.HOTEL_CATEGORY_CHOICES)
  company = CompanySerializer()
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it didn't work. I get exactly the same result.

Comment: Too bad. I will have to go try it and see why it doesn’t work. I believe I have used that before. Note that there is a reason why DRF doesn’t work this way. Just like you are using define variables to ensure your code does not change if you user friendly string changes, you should give your API user the same benefit. So the common thing to do is to have a short code for the user to use, which is different from the display string.